# Making a list of different types in Java

Tags: java, list, hierarchy, extends, superclass

I have a super class `Vehicle` and three classes that extend on it: `Bus`, `Car` and `Truck`. I want to have a linked list that will contain vehicles of different types, I use

```
list = new LinkedList<Vehicle>()
```

and it seems to work when I use `System.out.println(list.get(2))`, but I don't understand why? I've added as an experiment `toString()` function to `Vehicle` class which is deferent, but it still uses the extended classe's `toString()`. When will it use the father's function, and when it's sons?

All the different classes have the same functions, but different private variables.

the classes are:

```
public class Vehicle {

    protected String maker;
    protected int year;
    private int fuel; //0 1 2 3 4

    public Vehicle (String maker, int year) {
        this.maker = maker;
        this.year = year;
        this.fuel = 0;
    }

    public void drive () {...}

    public void fill () {...}
}
```

Bus:

```
public class Bus extends Vehicle{

    private int sits;

    public Bus (String maker, int year, int sits) {
        super (maker, year);
        this.sits = sits;
    }

    public String toString () {...}
}
```

Truck:

```
public class Truck extends Vehicle{

    private int weight;

    public Truck (String maker, int year, int weight) {
        super (maker, year);
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public String toString () {...}
}
```

Car:

```
public class Car extends Vehicle{

    private float volume;

    public Car (String maker, int year, float volume) {
        super (maker, year);
        this.volume = volume;
    }

    public String toString () {...}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it? what have you seen?

Comment: Have you tried `list = new LinkedList<Vehicle>()` and `System.out.println(list.get(2))`? If yes, what is it that you don't understand about what you found out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ofcourse you can make a `List` that contains `Vehicle` objects:

```
List<Vehicle> list = new LinkedList<Vehicle>();
```

When you do `System.out.println(list.get(2));` then it will get the `Vehicle` object at index 2 and call `toString()` on it, and then this string is printed to the console (you can ofcourse easily try that out yourself).

Note that if you want to call a method that is specific to a `Bus`, `Truck` or `Car` (i.e., defined in one of those classes and not in a superclass), then there is no way to do that without casting the result of `list.get(...)`.

You can call any method that's declared in class `Vehicle` (or superclasses - `toString()` is declared in class `Object`) without casting, and the method appropriate for the specific object (`Bus`, `Truck` or `Car`) will be called - that's what [polymorphism](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html) is all about.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that'll work without type casting as long as the differences are private.  That'll change the moment you add a method to one that doesn't appear in the interface.